# Uniform convergence of random functions

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, uniform-convergence

I am trying to understand the concept of uniform convergence in probability. Suppose we have a sequence of random functions $M_n(\theta)$ that converge uniformly in probability to $0$,

$$ \sup\limits_{\theta \in \Theta}|M_n(\theta)| \xrightarrow{P} 0 $$

where $\Theta$ is a compact set. Then would the statement still hold if $\theta$ were not deterministic, but a random sequence $\theta_n \in \Theta$?

From a statistical point of view, this would be like proving consistency but with a plug-in estimator of $\theta$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because, for every $\omega$ in the sample space, $|M_n(\theta (\omega))| \leq \sup_{\theta \in \Theta} |M_n(\theta)|$.

Comment: Thank you. For this to make sense, I'm assuming that $\theta_n$ has to be defined on the same probability space as $M_n$?

Comment: @JohnDoe1234 Yes, that is right.